# Wordpress Issues - Functionphp not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting stuck when it comes to enqueuing my stylesheets and scripts, they refuse to show up on the actual WordPress theme and sometimes my edits can lead to the localhost error 500.

Below is my `functions.php`, I've added the `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` to their respective pages.

Any ideas?

```
 <?php

    function test_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'test-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'test-responsive', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/responsive.css');

    wp_enqueue_style( 'test-animate', get_template_directory_uri() . '/Assets/css/animate.css');

    wp_enqueue_style( 'test-component', get_template_directory_uri() . '/Assets/css/component.css');

    wp_enqueue_script( 'test-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . 'Assets/js/scripts.js');
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the $src parameters look incorrect for [wp_enqueue_style()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) and [wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/). Is the directory named "Assets" or "assets" on the server? You are missing a "/" with the last wp_enqueue_script(). The code below should work if "assets" is lowercase.

```
function test_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'test-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'test-responsive', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/responsive.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'test-animate', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/animate.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'test-component', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/component.css');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'test-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scripts.js');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test_scripts' );
```

Comment: I tried the one you posted and I'm still not getting anything. The file is named with the "A" capitalized but it still didn't help. I don't know what I could be missing.

Comment: So you changed the $src to /Assets/ and still no luck? I'm not sure. The code worked on my own site.

Comment: Sorry for the late late late response, ultimately it started working for me - I had plenty of problems outside of the code that I used as example above. So many problems that I just scrapped it and started from scratch, so I assume it could've been a bunch of issues. Thank you for the help though, Im much more organized now!